# How to change a calender tables last week value from 1 to a continuous value

Tags: sql, t-sql

**Initial Point:**
I create a calender table with a function (see below). I use this table e.g. to sum entries for each week in the current year.

**Problem:**
The calculations are wrong for the first week, since the last week in the year has the value 1 as well as the first week in the year.

**Question:**
Since the calender table is used for many different queries it is not possible to solve this with just a 'Where' Clause modification. Is it possible to create a calender table where the weeks are just continuous including the last week?

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fct_Days_Periode](@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime) RETURNS @RET TABLE
 ( DateA datetime,
  Year as YEAR(DateA),
  QuarterNr as DATEPART(quarter, DateA),
  Quarter as 'Quarter '+CAST(DATEPART(quarter, DataA) as varchar(10)),
  MonthNr as MONTH(DataA),
  MonthA as DATENAME(month, DateA),
  KW as DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DataA),
  WeekdayA as DATENAME(weekday, DataA)
 )
AS
BEGIN
 WHILE @startDate<=@endDate
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @RET (DataA) VALUES (@startDate)
  SET @startDate=DATEADD(day, 1, @startDate)
 END
 RETURN
END
```

Comment: Oh, I use this function just once to create the table. Afterwards it is static.

Comment: If you're wanting to use `ISO_WEEK` as the week numbers, shouldn't you instead be adjusting the reported year instead? I.e. if `ISO_WEEK` is returning 1 but you're in december, you're actually working with week 1 of the following year so `YEAR()` is returning the wrong value.

Comment: Works as designed or that's how ISO Week works. The first week of a year is the first week with at least 4 days. And the last fragment of the previous year is a part of that first week.

Comment: ah, ok. If I would change isoweek to week would that solve my problem?